# Using UDP fsockopen to get info from file on gameserver

Tags: php

I got a file on a gameserver called "current_map.tmp".
This file contains a number depending on the current map.
What I need is to read that number.

This is what I got so far:

```
<?php

$server_ip = '213.239.207.85';
$server_port = 27960;
$server_timeout = 2;

$server_addr = "udp://" . $server_ip;

$fp = fsockopen($server_addr, $server_port, $errno, $errstr, $server_timeout);
socket_set_timeout ($fp, $server_timeout);

if (!$fp) {
    echo "ERROR: $errno - $errstr<br />\n";
    } else {
    $File = "current_map.tmp";
    $filesize = filesize($File);
    $handle = fopen($File, "r");  
    $map_id = fread($handle, $filesize);  
    fclose($handle);

    }

fclose($fp);

?>
```

$fp returns "Resource id #2".
So that works.

Then there is nothing.

1) How do I know wich folder I connected to with $fp?
2) How can I read the content of this file?

Comment: It would seem that you connected to the root folder at the requested address. Do you know the path to current_map.tmp?

Comment: Yes, thought of that too and failed to mention it.
When I put in the foldernames that are after Home, there is no result either

Comment: you do something very wrongly. UDP doesn't give you access to the file-system. UDP just lets you sending (or receiving) byte-streams without guaranteed delivery.

Comment: Oh dear... 
Anyone knows how I can access the file then?

Answer (score 0):

> `$fp` returns "Resource id #2". So that works.

No; this doesn't actually mean anything! Since UDP sockets are connectionless, there is no such thing as a UDP "connection"; calling `fsockopen()` only initializes sockets to prepare to send packets.

In any case, sending and receiving UDP packets does not allow you to access files on a remote server, unless that server has implemented a protocol to allow you to do so, and you are making use of that protocol. It certainly will not allow you to use `fopen()` to access remote files — this code is essentially just nonsense.